# Rectangle function that takes in two points and makes a rectangle in a global matrix not working

Tags: python

I have a matrix of 50 by 50 that represents a grid of 25 by 25.

I want all the positives on the grid to get +25 and the negatives stay there absolute value.

But what my problem actually is I am creating a function that will create a rectangle based on the given values.

Code (Python 3.10.5):

```
def createRect(x,y,x1,y1,item):
    global matrix
    for i in range(x1,x,-1):
         matrix[i][y1]=item
        
    for i in range(y1,y-1,-1):
        matrix[x][i] = item

    for j in range(1,6):    
        for i in range(y1-1,y-1,-1):
            matrix[x+j][i] = item
    
matrix = [['. ']*50 for _ in range(50)]

x,y,x1,y1 = 25+2,25+5,25+7,25+9
x2,y2,x3,y3 = 25+6,25+2,25+9,25+10

createRect(x,y,x1,y1,'# ')
createRect(x2,y2,x3,y3,'- ')


for i in range(50):
    for j in range(50):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = "")
    print()
```

I tried using the function on another set of points but it only works for the first one seeing as its the only rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about your code there, as why you fill the matrix backwards (`for i in range(x1,x,-1)`) and why would you include a hardcoded `6` there (`for j in range(1,6)`) so I might as well not have understood what the problem is. But wouldn't the following create the rectangles as per the given points? ：

```
def createRect(x, y, x1, y1, item):
    global matrix
    
    for i in range(x, x1+1):
        for j in range(y, y1+1):
            matrix[i][j] = item
```